# How can I make my USDZ background transparent/black in my Xcode build?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

Does anyone knows how I could make the background of the USDZ files transparent or black in color? When building my Xcode project I can't seem to make the background black in color, even with changing the USDZ's background and lighting to the colour black.
I have attached the code here below.
Unfortunately I won't upload the USDZ files since I couldn't find a way to share it.

```
//  ContentView.swift
//  USDZviewer
//
//  Created by Conqueriings on 31/10/21.
// CREDITS: Kavsoft

import SwiftUI
import SceneKit
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Home()
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Home()
    }
}
struct Home : View {
    
    @State var models = [
        Model(id: 0, name: "Cookie", modelName: "cookie.usdz"),
        Model(id: 0, name: "Micro:Bit (Front)", modelName: "mbfront.usdz"),
        Model(id: 0, name: "Micro:Bit (Back)", modelName: "mb2.usdz"),
        Model(id: 0, name: "RaspberryPi 4", modelName: "RPIv5.usdz")
    ]
    
    @State var index = 0
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack {
            SceneView(scene: SCNScene(named: models[index].modelName), options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting, .allowsCameraControl])
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
                
            
            
            ZStack{
                HStack{
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation{
                            if index > 0{
                                index -= 1
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                            .font(.system(size: 35, weight: .bold))
                            .opacity(index == 0 ? 0.3 : 1)
                    })
                        .disabled(index == 0 ? true : false)
                    
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        withAnimation{
                            if index < models.count{
                                index += 1
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }, label: {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                            .font(.system(size: 35, weight: .bold))
                        // disabling button when no other data ....
                            .opacity(index == models.count - 1 ? 0.3 : 1)
                    })
                        .disabled(index == models.count - 1 ? true : false)
                }
                
                Text(models[index].name)
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold))
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.vertical,30)
        }
        
    }
}
// Data Model...
struct Model : Identifiable {
    
    var id : Int
    var name : String
    var modelName : String
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I was able to create a black background using:

```
SceneView(
    scene: {
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "modelName")
        
        scene!.background.contents = UIColor.black
        
        
    }() ,options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting]
)
```